# Jest Test "Compared values have no visual difference."

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm doing a comparison between two objects that are quite complex and attempting to use the .toEqual method in expect.

Here is my test:

```
it('check if stepGroups data in controlData matches data in liveData', () =>    {
    var controlStore = data.controlStore
    var liveStore
    return getData().then(result => {
        liveStore = new Store()
        liveStore.loadData(JSON.parse(result))
        expect(controlStore).toEqual(liveStore)  
    })
})
```

I did a diff between the expected and the the received output and they both appear to be the same.  What would still be causing this test to fail?  I was reading up on pretty-format (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1622).  Have you run into similar situations?

Answer (score 26):

use `expect(JSON.stringify(controlStrore)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(liveStore))`

Comment: I tried this but test is still not getting succeeded

Comment: Nice solutions! +1

Answer (score 12):

In your code sample you are comparing two instances of `Store`, which encapsulate some data. Thus even if data (`result` json in your case) is the same, it doesn't necessarily imply that both container instances can be considered equal.

It should be possible to do something like `expect(controlStore.getState()).toEqual(liveStore.getState())`.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend using `JSON.stringify` as it might hide an underlying problem. In my experience, this error mostly occurs when an array is assigned a key that is not a positive integer. Example:

```
  const arr = [1]
  arr.a = 'b'
  expect(arr).toEqual([1])
```

The test fails with the error `Compared values have no visual difference`. To understand what is going on I recommend to log the object and then adapt the test case as necessary.

```
console.log(arr)
// logs [ 1, a: 'b' ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. In my case, the array had an '-1' key that wasn't being displayed by Jest, but the use of console.log() pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably trying to set a method via a lambda-function in your Store class. So jest is trying to compare to different functions, which were generated separately each time you do `new Store()`. As a result it rises an error, though it cant display difference, it just cant print functions.

Comment: I had a similar issue... I suspect the solution is to compare the functions within the object. I was satisfied, however, that the desired properties were present and - therefore - the required code had been returned

Answer (score 1):

If you compare objects, that should be `deep equal` not just `equal`, for example:

```js
import chai from 'chai'
chai.should()

controlStore.should.be.deep.equal(liveStore)
```

Comment: it really worked on vitest framework,